# repeat indices with different repeat values in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I'm looking for an efficient way to do the following with Numpy:

Given a array `counts` of positive integers containing for instance:

`[3, 1, 0, 6, 3, 2]`

I would like to generate another array containing the indices of the first one, where the index `i` is repeated `counts[i]` times:

`[0 0 0 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5]`

My problem is that this array is potentially very large and I'm looking for a vectorial (or fast) way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy-repeat):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([3, 1, 0, 6, 3, 2])
repix = np.repeat(np.arange(arr.size), arr)
print(repix)
```

Output:

```
[0 0 0 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5]
```

Comment: Thanks! I looked at numpy.repeat but from the documentation I didn't understand that it could also be used this way.